# Use data retrieved from database with javascript

Tags: javascript, function, node.js

I have this code

```
App.Model('users').find(function (err, users) {
        users.forEach(function(user) {
        console.log(user.username);
    });
});

//make usernames availible here.
```

This console logs the usernames. 
Instead of just logging to the console I want make use of the data.

But How can do this?

Thanks

Comment: You want to make use of the data? What does that mean? Do you want to build a list of usernames? Or maybe a list of user objects?

Comment: assign to a variable so that can display on the screen for example.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: You need to adapt to the callback style of programming or drop node.js :)

Comment: "Welcome to the wonderful world of async! You can't do that." CLASSIC.

Comment: Node.js is event-driven. What do you want to do with the usernames?

Comment: The "event-driven", "non-blocking", "asyn", "callback" is starting to make sense to me now. I think you answered my question with actually answering it. I Will read up more and re-factor my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will never be available where you want them. This isn't how async/node.js programming works.

Possible:

```
App.Model('users').find(function (err, users) {
    users.forEach(function(user) {
        myCallBack(user);
    });
});

var myCallBack = function(user) {
    //make usernames availible here.
    //this will be called with every user object
    console.log(user);
}
```

Other possibilites: [EventEmitter](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html), flow controll libraries (e.g. [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)).

If you have written code in other languages before you need to be open to take a complete new approach how data will be handled.

Answer (score 0):

With node js you don't do:

```
//make usernames availible here.
```

You do:

```
App.Model('users').find(function (err, users) {
    //usernames are available here. Pass them somewhere. Notify some subscribers that you have data.
});

//The code here has executed a long time ago
```